# rclpy.time.Time() vs Node.get_clock().now()

Tags: ros2, rclpy, use-sim-time

I'm using Ubuntu 22, ROS2 Humble, Gazebo 11. I tried to print the same value in two different ways that are:

```
rclpy.time.Time()
Node.get_clock().now()
```

The time coming from `rclpy.time.Time()` is the simulator time, which is the same as the output of the topic `/clock`. While the output of the latter method yields the "absolute" time of the computer.

The question is:

1. What is the cause for this behavior?
2. What would be the more robust method to extract current sim-time?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
The following links can help: [ROS 2 Design: Clock and Time](https://design.ros2.org/articles/clock_and_time.html), [Replacement for rospy.time.now() in ROS2?](https://answers.ros.org/question/321536/replacement-for-rospytimenow-in-ros2/)

Answer (score 1):

Using the default constructor for `rclpy.time.Time()` will just give you a default constructed time.

```
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from rclpy import time
>>> time.Time()
Time(nanoseconds=0, clock_type=SYSTEM_TIME)
```

It will be zero, which is simulated time if started in pause. But won't continue to change.

Whereas the clock that is attached to a node has a Time Source attached to it. Defining the `clock_type` parameter you see above. And the clock attached to the node will be paying attention to whether your node has the parameter `use_simulated_time` set on it. And give you simulated time or not depending on the parameter setting as outlined in [the design document](https://design.ros2.org/articles/clock_and_time.html)

So tl;dr you should be using the clock associated with the node to get the time.

There's another improper pattern that you could default construct a `Clock` and not associate a `TimeSource` with it (which the Node does for you) but shouldn't do that as it will break expectations of how a clock should work in the system.